# Centred, absolutely positioned element looking good in all but Firefox7 for windows

Tags: css, firefox, center, css-position, firefox7

I have managed to get my absolutely positioned menu looking good in all but Firefox 7 for Windows (according to Browserlab).

http://chantalwholesalers.co.nz/wordpress/

The CSS:

```
#primary-menu {
    margin-right: -490px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
}
```

Not quite sure why it is different in just Firefox 7 for Windows? Also seem to have an issue with the footer, not sure if that is related.

Tips? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is clear you #container div.

```
#container { clear: both; }
```

Comment: Thanks peduate! But I'm still seeing the issue (in Browserlab). Does it look ok to you?

Comment: Ok, must be Browserlab. I am on a Mac so can't check. Thanks again!

Comment: I checked FF on Mac and Windows.